# Reason for division by standard deviations in proof of showing correlation coefficient is $1$.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, covariance, correlation

I was reading a proof in *Mathematical Statistics by Rice* establishing that the correlation coefficient, $\rho$, is such that $-1 \leq \rho \leq 1$. Here is the proof:

[image]

I have a few questions:

1. What was the reasoning behind taking the sum of the random variables besides "it working out" ? i.e: why $\frac{X}{\sigma_{X}} + \frac{Y}{\sigma_{Y}}$?
2. Why the choice to normalize the random variables ? i.e: why $\frac{X - 0}{\sigma_{X}}$
3. Why are we allowed to assume that $\mu_{X} = 0$ ? same for  $Y$

Comment: It looks as if someone wrote $2\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ instead of $2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y).$ How do people manage to be so unobservant about typography?

Comment: 2) It's very common to consider the normalized version of a random variable $X^* := 
 \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, e.g. in the Central Limit Theorem. This is so different random variables are "on the same footing" and "can be fairly compared". The correlation coefficient is then just $\mathbb{E}[X^* Y^*]$, which is quite natural. 1) The correlation coefficient is intuitively something like a "cross term" in $(X^* \pm Y^*)^2$. The proof just takes expectations of this. 3) These shifts don't matter; the variances and covariances are the same if you ignore them.

Comment: Thanks for this @JoshuaP.Swanson....It provided the clarification I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative proof (it's just a morning brainstorming...):

Suppose that $Y=a+bX$ is just an estimation of Y, so not with Proability 1.

As known, this is a linear interpolation Y based on X.

The estimation of the slope is $\hat{b}=\rho\cdot \frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X}}$

Now let's calculate

$\rho=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}=\frac{\mathbb{E}[(a+bX)X]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[a+bX]}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}=\frac{a\mathbb{E}[X]+b\mathbb{E}[X^2]-a\mathbb{E}[X]-b\mathbb{E}^2[X]}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}=\frac{b\mathbb{V}[X]}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}=b\frac{\sigma_{X}}{\sigma_{Y}}$

Now it is self evident that if

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=a+bX]=1$$

(it's almost sure that $Y=a+bX$) we can substitute $b$ with $\hat{b}$ with no errors and this prove the statement that $\rho=1$

Similar argument holds if the line is decreasing and $\rho=-1$